# Mobile responsive view is not showing nav-links what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
  if (x.className === "nav-bar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav-bar";
  }
}
```

```css
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav-bar{
  position:fixed;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
}
 .sticky {
   top: 0;
   opacity: 1;
  }
.nav-bar a{
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(82,101,143,1);
  font-size: 20px;  
}
.nav-bar a:hover {
    color: #CFCFCF;
}
.nav-bar .icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-bar a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .nav-bar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-bar.responsive {position: relative;}
  .nav-bar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .nav-bar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <nav id=#navbar><div class="nav-bar text-center">
            <a href="#about">About Us</a>
            <a href=#visa>Visa Application</a>
            <a href="#fund">Fund</a>
            <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact us</a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
             <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
         </div>
       </nav>
   </div>
```

i'm trying to make the nav bar small screen responsive, the hamburger bar appears however it doesn't give me the nav-link options, what am i doing wrong?
i can get one link to permanently show with the not first-child but this dosnt really help as i would like to to show nothing by default and then produce the option on click

https://codepen.io/courtneypunx/pen/abBpGeY

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
          <nav id=#navbar><div class="nav-bar text-center">
            <a href="#about">About Us</a>
            <a href=#visa>Visa Application</a>
            <a href="#fund">Fund</a>
            <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact us</a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
             <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
         </div>
       </nav>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav-bar{
  position:fixed;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
}
 .sticky {
   top: 0;
   opacity: 1;
  }
.nav-bar a{
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(82,101,143,1);
  font-size: 20px;  
}
.nav-bar a:hover {
    color: #CFCFCF;
}
.nav-bar .icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-bar a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .nav-bar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-bar.responsive {position: relative;}
  .nav-bar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .nav-bar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
  if (x.className === "nav-bar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav-bar";
  }
}
```

Comment: try using `x.classList.add("responsive")` instead of `x.className += " responsive`

Comment: i changed as you said but it didn't change anything, i'm thinking the problem is in the CSS @media section

Comment: First of all, the Id in your HTML has a typo which should be `<nav id='navbar'>`. Second, your JS is a function, so you need to call it first before working. Third, `.nav-bar{ opacity: 0}` has zero opacity, it won't show because of this one.